# Windows can't read the disk

Tags: windows-7, dvd, compact-disc

I want to write some data on a Disk. but when I insert the disk in my DVD-RW and do a double click on it, the below windows appear. why?

I tried with different CDs and DVDs, But nothing change!

I can read the other CDs, but I can't open empty Disks. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Control Panel` `->` `Services` and Search for `Shell Hardware Detection` service.
If it is `disabled` then set it to `Automatic`.

Now everything should work as well.